# Accessing SXA Site Grouping Site Settings Properties from Code

Tags: sxa, sitecore-api

I have a SXA site created and under "/settings/Site Grouping" I have defined a Site item.

I want to access "Other Properties" fields (ex: "dictionaryPath" which I have added into Other properties) using Sitecore api.

I hope these properties are getting merged into SiteInfo property like it does when we define it in the "site" settings definition in the configuration files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These items can be queried using code like this:

```
var siteInfo = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISiteInfoResolver>().GetSiteInfo(Context.Item);
if (siteInfo != null)
{
    var siteContext = new SiteContext(siteInfo);
    var dictionaryPath = siteContext.Properties["dictionaryPath"];
}
```