# How to access the Settings folder in an SXA Site programmatically?

Tags: sxa

I created a `Tenant` under which I have multiple `Sites`. I want to access the `Settings` folder of each `Site` and perform some action on it.

This is the current structure:
Tenant ABC contains Site ABC. Site ABC has basic SXA Site structure, having items like Home, Data, Media, Presentations & Settings. I want to access the Settings folder of all Sites under my Tenant ABC.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17908/accessing-sxa-site-grouping-site-settings-properties-from-code/17909

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
var contextItem = Context.Item;
if (contextItem == null) return;

var siteItem = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMultisiteContext>().GetSiteItem(contextItem);

var settingsItem = siteItem?.Children["Settings"];
if (settingsItem == null) return;
```

Comment: FYI - `IMultisiteContext` has a `GetSettingsItem` method on it :) even easier